# "Blow" in a conversation

Tags: vocabulary, colloquial-language

Can "Blow" be used by itself to mean "Blow something up all out of proportion?"

As in:

> She was written off as **Blowing** it (a situation) in an attempt to
>   implicate him.

(Made up example)

Comment: Sorry guys but I just cannot get my head around what is going on with this sentence or the suggested one in the answer from @katatahito. Unless there are some unknown meanings in US English I am not aware of I can make no sense of both of the sentences. To me they sound like a few English phrases (which have been wrongly interrupted) just strung together which  sound like gibberish to me.

Comment: @Brad To me it means "She was dismissed as just exaggerating it to try and implicate him". i.e. A witness in a murder trial makes a big deal that the accused had lied to her about something insignificant to defame their character, trying to make it more likely that the jury will convict them. Albeit, this phrasing is a little weird but it is understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least without surrounding context, no that is no the meaning for **blow** received from your sentence.

"Blow it" already has a more common idiomatic expression:

> [blow it](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/blow+it)
>
> > *slang*: To ruin, mishandle, or fail to capitalize on an opportunity.

Therefore it sounds like the woman failed an opportunity (apparently on purpose) to try to implicate a man.

---

A slightly better phrasing could be:

> She was written off as [just] blowing it up in an attempt to implicate him.

This phrasing will not be parsed as the definition referenced above, instead it will mean something closer to your desired definition.

Comment: As I was reading the last part of your answer, it hit me that _up_ is what I must've missed noticing wherever I heard or saw the phrase. Thanks for pointing that out to me!